# Limit text area to 6 lines (Rows) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, textarea

I'm trying to limit the user to only 6 lines of text (Or rows) in the textarea.
If I limit the characters to for example 60 lines, the user can enter 59 times and have a character in the line 60. I want to avoid that by limiting the user to 60 characters but in a max 6 lines in the textarea. Or disable the enter button in the text area will also do the trick. I found some solutions for jquery but I'm trying to stay with Javascript/React.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a couple of options:

- [Textarea max length](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_maxlength.asp)
- [Textarea rows](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_textarea_rows.asp)

Comment: As mentioned above, character limit still gives the user the chance of having one character per line and hit enter as many characters as availible. And limit the row will not actually limit the rows a textarea can have, just the ones you can see, then it goes to overflow.